# True keyboard mimic in python

Tags: python, user-interface, ctypes, pywin32

I need to be able to mimic the keyboard function "ctrl+c" to copy highlighted texts.  But that's not it... I have tried ctypes, pywin32api, pywin32, pyautogui, 
pywinauto, ... and just about every other module out there.  I know how to use them all.  I have also made other successful auto gui programs.

The problem is that I'm trying to automate a program on a windows computer that is not a native windows program.  When I physically press "ctrl+c" in the program it works and copies the data.  But when I use any of the modules to simulate a hotkey function they simply fail and don't copy to clipboard.  So I need to fully, completely, exactly, and in every way MIMIC keystrokes in windows.  Is there a module out there that can do this?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried to use the SendInput or SendMessage (with specific key messages) windows APIs? Also, what do you mean exactly by "not a native windows program"? Do you have the same or a higher privilege than the  application you're trying to send keys to?

Comment: I believe pywinauto uses SendKeys..  It's like a wrapper for win api.  I say this because pywinauto format is to use "{ENTER}" for example.  Which is the same for windows key arqumaents for windows api on windows website.  So, Yes I have indirectly tried sendkeys.   What I'm experiencing here is very odd

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion tho

Comment: I looked further into it and you were absolutly correct.  pywinauto is the best way to do this.  But to pull it off I had to look into windows api on their website.  Thanks.  If you reply I will mark it as answered

Comment: if anyone is curious:  you must create a control on a window using pyinauto and use handle_grabbed_on_to.TypeKeys("^c")

Comment: @caelator, I would be glad to hear which pywinauto docs pages did you look at. And what is the most confusing or insufficiently clear for you? We really appreciate detailed feedback about the docs.

Comment: BTW, `pywinauto.SendKeysCtypes.SendKeys("^c")` is available if you don't want to call `Application.Connect(path="your.exe")` and then `app.MainWindow.TypeKeys("^c")`. P.S. We're planning to rename it to `pywinauto.keyboard.type("^c")` in the future major release.